# How can I make C-m1 emulate a right click?

Tags: xorg, xfce, mouse, input

On Mac OS X, you can right click by holding down control and clicking. I swapped the command and control keys with `setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_win`, but how do I make it right click by holding down control and clicking? I am on a Powerbook G4 with Debian XFCE.

UPDATE:

Chris Down's answer requires you to press control and click at *exactly* the same time. On Mac you can **hold down** control and click.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that some things may not work as you expect after doing this (for example, Firefox and other browsers use this for their "open in new tab" functionality).

First, you'll need to install `xbindkeys` via your package manager, then do the following:

```
xbindkeys –defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
cat >> ~/.xbindkeysrc << 'EOF'
"xvkbd -text '\m3'"
mod4 + b:1 (mouse)
EOF
xbindkeys -n -v
```

To have this functionality every time you start your DE, add `xbindkeys -n -v` to your startup programs.

Comment: Thanks, but this requires you to press control and click at _exactly_ the same time. On Mac you can **hold down** control and click.